# How do I get an activity go back to the previous activity which is not the parent?

Tags: java, android

I got activities A, B, and C. They all navigate forward and back fine. During any of these 3 activities I can start a glossary activity. When I go back/up, no matter what the previous activity was, it goes to activity A (it's parent as defined in the manifest). Do I need to change something in the manifest?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, glossary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: So here you want to switch over Activity A in any situation (Whether you have started glossary from A or B or C ). Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if changing anything in the manifest would help. You could try below code where we are overriding the implementation of the "Up" button and calling `onBackPressed()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return(true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Let me know if this helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the previous `Activity` on the stack (the one before you start your `GlossaryActivity`), you don't need to define the parent `Activity` of your `GlossaryActivity`, so you only need to remove this line in the manifest.

Then, when you will press the back button, it will automatically close your current Activity and go back to the previous.

Another point : if you are using the `ActionBar` or `Toolbar` arrow that do the same thing as the back button, you should do this in you `GlossaryActivity`to go back to the previous `Activity` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);
    ...
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```